# Scala Future strange compile error

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Code below is a simplified version of the real code. We "inherited" the domain model `case object FutTest` and `case class FutTest`, which we can't modify. The actual domain models are served from a Database, so I believe the `Future approach` is valid, but it causes problems which I don't understand.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSpec
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case object FutTest {
  def create(sz: Int) = { FutTest(sz) }
}

case class FutTest(size: Int)

class FutureTest extends FunSpec {
  def one(v: Int): Future[FutTest] = {
    Future { FutTest.create(v) }
  }
  def two(t: FutTest) = {
    Future { FutTest.create(t.size) }
  }

  def compileError1: Future[FutTest] = {
    one(10).map(f => two(f))
  }

  def compileError2: Future[FutTest] = {
    for { o <- one(10) } yield (two(o))
  }
}
```

The error messages:

```
[INFO] Using incremental compilation
[INFO] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 5 .. target/test-classes...
[ERROR] domain.FutureTest.scala:25: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[domain.FutTest]
 required: domain.FutTest
[ERROR]     one(10).map(f => two(f))
[ERROR]                         ^
[ERROR] domain/FutureTest.scala:29: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[domain.FutTest]
 required: domain.FutTest
[ERROR]     for { o <- one(10) } yield (two(o))
```

I tried the above code with plain `Int` instead of `FutTest` and all is fine. Why is the compiler complaining and how can we solve this without touching the existing domain.

Comment: I don't believe that this works if you replace `FutTest` with `Int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

flatMap is what you want.

```
one(10).flatMap(f => two(f))
```

or

```
one(10).flatMap(two)
```

Using for comprehension,

```
for { o <- one(10); t <- two(o) } yield t
```

Answer (score 4):

`One()` returns a `Future` and `two()` also returns a `Future` so you need to `flatMap` instead of `map`. When you map to `two()`, your result is `Future[Future[FutTest]]` and needs to be flattened.

Doing

```
one(10).flatMap(f => two(f))
```

should do the trick.